# Expected value of exp(X^3)] , X~(mu,sigma^2)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Any shortcut in calculating

$$\operatorname E[e^3X ],\qquad X\sim N(μ,\sigma^2)\text{ ?}$$

Insted of having to compute the integral? I'm having a hard time with this integral.

Comment: Do you want $\operatorname E(\exp(X^3))$ or $\operatorname E(e^{3X})$ or something else? $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $\Big( \exp(X) \Big)^3$ is the same as $\exp(3X),$ but that is not the same as $\exp(X^3). \qquad$

Comment: In my answer below you see that you don't need to evaluate the integral from scratch. But you do need to know how to complete the square and otherwise how to do algebra.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's really $E(\exp(X^3))$ that you want, that integral diverges and so the expected value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant $\operatorname E(e^{3X})$ rather than what you have in the subject line.

Presumably you already know that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2} \, dx = 1.$

We seek $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{3x} e^{-(1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2} \, dx.$

We have $e^{3x} e^{-(1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2} = e ^{3x - (1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2}.$ We'll work on the exponent.
\begin{align}
3x - \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{x-\mu}\sigma \right)^2 & = -\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac{-6x\sigma^2 + (x^2 - 2x\mu + \mu^2)}{\sigma^2} \\[10pt]
& = - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} \left( x^2 - 2(\mu+3\sigma^2) x + \mu^2 \right) \\[10pt]
& = - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2}\Big( (x - 2(\mu+3\sigma^2) + (\mu + 3\sigma^2)^2 + \Big[ \mu^2  -(\mu + 3\sigma^2)^2\Big] \Big) \\
& \qquad\qquad (\text{completing the square}) \\[12pt]
& = - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} (x-(\cdots))^2 + \Big( \text{something not depending on $x$} \Big)
\end{align}
Thus our integral is
$$
\frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1/2)(x - (\cdots))^2} \, dx \times e^{(\text{something not depending on $x$})}.
$$
The value of this integral is $1$ for the same reason the value of the first integral mentioned above is $1.$ The factor after the integral is what you seek.